# Can I use should.js with QtScript?

Tags: c++, node.js, qt, should.js, qtscript

I'm using QtScript to automate parts of my application for development and testing purposes.  I've come to the point where I want to test assertions, and based on ["standalone assertion libraries?"](/a/10480546/4850040) and what I could find in Debian repositories, I went for Should.js.

I'm having trouble loading it into my Qt application, as it depends on Node's `require()` function.  I tried implementing a version of this, starting from ["Supporting require() of CommonJS"](http://www.shibu.jp/techmemo/qtscript.html#supporting-require-of-commonjs) and ending up with the code below.

Can it be made to work, or am I doomed in this approach?  Would I perhaps be better off copying the bits of should.js into a single file?  I'd prefer not to make myself responsible for keeping a fork up to date.  (Licensing is a non-issue, as I don't intend to redistribute this code).

Here's my MCVE; sorry I couldn't get it any shorter!

#### should.cpp

```c++
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QScriptEngine>
#include <QScriptContext>
#include <QScriptContextInfo>
#include <QTextStream>


// Primitive implementation of Node.js require().
// N.B. Supports only .js sources.
QScriptValue require(QScriptContext* context, QScriptEngine* engine)
{
    const QString moduleName = context->argument(0).toString();

    // First, look in our modules cache
    QScriptValue modules = engine->globalObject().property("$MODULES");
    QScriptValue module = modules.property(moduleName);
    if (module.isValid()) {
        auto cached_file = module.property("filename");
        auto time_stamp = module.property("timestamp");
        auto code = module.property("code");
        if (code.isObject() && cached_file.isString() && time_stamp.isDate()) {
            if (QFileInfo(cached_file.toString()).lastModified() == time_stamp.toDateTime()) {
                qDebug() << "found up-to-date module for require of" << moduleName;
                return code;
            } else {
                qDebug() << "cache stale for" << moduleName;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Prepare a cache entry, as some modules recursively include each
        // other.  This way, they at least get the partial definition of the
        // other, rather than a stack overflow.
        module = engine->newObject();
        modules.setProperty(moduleName, module);
    }

    qDebug() << "require" << moduleName;

    // resolve filename relative to the calling script
    QString filename = moduleName + ".js";
    for (auto *p = context;  p;  p = p->parentContext()) {
        QScriptContextInfo info(p);
        auto parent_file = info.fileName();
        if (parent_file.isEmpty())
            continue;
        // else, we reached a context with a filename
        QDir base_dir = QFileInfo(parent_file).dir();
        filename = base_dir.filePath(filename);
        if (QFile::exists(filename)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    QFile file(filename);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        return context->throwValue(QString("Failed to open %0").arg(moduleName));
    }

    QTextStream in(&file);
    in.setCodec("UTF-8");
    auto script = in.readAll();
    file.close();

#if 0
    // I had to disable this, because it barfs on "get not()" definition - is
    // that a Node extension?  Will it cause me problems even if I get require()
    // working?
    auto syntax_check = QScriptEngine::checkSyntax(script);
    if (syntax_check.state() != QScriptSyntaxCheckResult::Valid) {
        return context->throwValue(QString("%2:%0:%1: Syntax error: %3")
                                   .arg(syntax_check.errorLineNumber())
                                   .arg(syntax_check.errorColumnNumber())
                                   .arg(filename, syntax_check.errorMessage()));
    }
#endif

    // create a new context, and capture the module's exports
    QScriptContext* newContext = engine->pushContext();
    QScriptValue exports = engine->newObject();
    newContext->activationObject().setProperty("exports", exports);
    module.setProperty("code", exports);
    module.setProperty("filename", filename);
    module.setProperty("timestamp", engine->newDate(QFileInfo(filename).lastModified()));
    // run the script
    engine->evaluate(script, filename);
    // get the exports
    module.setProperty("code", newContext->activationObject().property("exports"));
    engine->popContext();
    if (engine->hasUncaughtException())
        return engine->uncaughtException();
    qDebug() << "loaded" << moduleName;
    return exports;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QScriptEngine engine;

    // register global require() function
    auto global = engine.globalObject();
    global.setProperty("require", engine.newFunction(require));
    global.setProperty("$MODULES", engine.newObject());

    engine.evaluate("var should = require('/usr/lib/nodejs/should/lib/should');");

    if (engine.hasUncaughtException()) {
        qCritical() << engine.uncaughtException().toString().toStdString().c_str();
        qWarning() << engine.uncaughtExceptionBacktrace().join("\n").toStdString().c_str();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Makefile

```make
check: should
    ./should

CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
CXXFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags Qt5Script)
LDLIBS += $(shell pkg-config --libs Qt5Script)
```

The output is

```
require "/usr/lib/nodejs/should/lib/should" 
require "./util" 
require "./inspect" 
found up-to-date module for require of "./util" 
loaded "./inspect" 
require "assert" 
Failed to open assert 
<eval>() at /usr/lib/nodejs/should/lib/./util.js:126
<native>() at -1
<native>('./util') at -1
<eval>() at /usr/lib/nodejs/should/lib/should.js:8
<native>() at -1
<native>('/usr/lib/nodejs/should/lib/should') at -1
<global>() at 1
```

(In passing - how do I get the actual function name `require` in the stack trace instead of `<native>`?  Slots manage this, so I should be able to, right?)

Comment: It fails to lookup ```require('assert')``` library, because search paths are not setup correctly. ```require()``` implementation should check for other require paths (within node_modules) [https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together). It should also have search path for core ```node.js``` modules which may be referenced from modules.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into it with little more detail and rewriting C++ Qt require system is a little bit more time consuming for me then initially thought. There is also issue with libraries having `require`-ing core modules (which in turn `require` native modules which would result in undefined behavior - read: probably won't work).

## Approach #1 - `C++ require()` implementation:

Implement custom `node` `require()` in C++ Qt like it has been started in your question and link. Details of workings of `node.js` `require()` can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together). You'll need to have core `node` modules in your `require()` search path (you can get them from `node.js` source repository).

## Approach #2 - Use `browserify`

Since the problem we are trying to solve in #1 is basically loading and caching javascript files, why not use something that already exists for the same purpose. This way we can avoid manual work and bundle `javascript` we have strong indication it will work on a browser (more limited environment then `node.js`).

```
$ npm install -g browserify
$ npm install expect
```

`index.js`

```
var expect = require('expect');
expect(1).toEqual(1);
```

And run `browserify`:

```
$ browserify index.js -o bundle.js
```

In your `Qt C++`:

```
QString script = loadFile("/path/to/bundle.js");
engine.evaluate(script);
```

We have come to a workaround for `require()` however I'm not certain of interop. with `Qt`. Also, I have encountered some `Syntax Error` from QtScript for some `js` modules so this is no silver bullet even on first it may seem so.

Note: this is also interesting project: https://github.com/svalaskevicius/qtjs-generator.

Comment: I've had to put this down for a while; when I pick it up again, I'll work through your answer (and mark it accepted if it solves my problem).  You've got the bounty, anyway.